# async within callback never resolving using express

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am trying to understand promises a little better. I was trying to make a simple `async delay` function that would set a timeout and then responds after a set timeout completes:

```
const app = express();

function timeout(duration) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout done');
      resolve('returned promise');
    }, duration)
  );
}

async function delay(duration) {
  let returnedPromise = await timeout(duration);
  console.log(returnedPromise);

}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Performance example: ${process.pid}`);
});


app.get('/timer', async (req, res) => {
  await delay(5000);
  res.send(`Ding ding sing! ${process.pid}`);
});

console.log('Worker process started.');
app.listen(3000);
```

this is the total function and it works as expected, responding after 5 seconds.

however, when i change the `app.get('/timer')` route to this i get a promise that never gets resolved:

```
app.get('/timer', (req, res) => {
  async () => {
    await delay(5000);
    res.send(`Ding ding ding! ${process.pid}`);
  };
});
```

I'm not sure why changing the `async` from before the callback to inside the callback makes a difference in this case

EDIT:

I didn't call the function :) this works:

```
app.get('/timer', (req, res) => {
  (async () => {
    await delay(5000);
    res.send(`Ding ding ding! ${process.pid}`);
  })();
});
```

Comment: You never _call_ the function in your last snippet.

Answer (score 0):

No need for your extra function inside in your edit as you can just do this:

```
app.get('/timer', async (req, res) => {
    await delay(5000);
    res.send(`Ding ding ding! ${process.pid}`);
});
```